# Distribution of a difference of two Uniform random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ both be distributed between $[1,2]$, what is the distribution of $Z=X-Y$?

Comment: Clearly, $Z$ has a range $[-1,1]$ so what are the problems of computing its density?

Comment: If you are interested in the answer only, try `PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  x - y, {Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]], 
   Distributed[y, UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]}], z]` in _Mathematica_. Otherwise state the origin of the problem, and share what you had attempted so far.

Comment: $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z+y)f_Y(y)dy=\int_{-1}^1f_X(z+y)dy$

Is this right?

Comment: @TarekAbed: $y\in [1,2]$ rather than in $[-1,1]$

Comment: @Ilya: 

$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z+y)f_Y(y)dy=\int_{1}^2f_X(z+y)dy$

What comes next?

Comment: @TarekAbed: next comes what is $f_X(z+y)$

Comment: @Ilya: It's $1$, isn't it?

Comment: @TarekAbed: hint - what is $f_X(z+y)$ when $z+y \notin [1,2]$?

Comment: @Ilya It's $0$.

Comment: @TarekAbed: so it's not exactly $1$ (an often typo when dealing with densities defined piece-wise), it's rather an indicator function - see the answer of copper.hat

Comment: Isn't the issue of (in)dependence of the two X,Y , relevant in some way( towards determining the resulting distribution)?

Answer (score 15):

If $x,y$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[1,2]$, then the PDF of $x$ is $1_{[1,2]}$ and the PDF of $-y$ (note the minus sign) is $1_{[-2,-1]}$. Then the PDF of $z=x-y$ is given by the convolution $f_z=1_{[1,2]} * 1_{[-2,-1]}$.

Computing this is straightforward.
\begin{eqnarray}
f_z(x) &=& \int 1_{[1,2]}(y) 1_{[-2,-1]}(x-y) dy \\
&=& \int_1^2  1_{[-2,-1]}(x-y) dy \\
&=& \int_{x-2}^{x-1}1_{[-2,-1]}(t) dt \\
&=& \int 1_{[x-2,x-1] \cap [-2,-1]}(t)dt \\
&=& m([x-2,x-1] \cap [-2,-1]) \\
&=& m([x,x+1] \cap [0,1]) \\
&=& (1-|x|)1_{[-1,1]}(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: What is m()? Also I dont get the second = where you go to using $t$.

Comment: @jacob: The $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, it is the length of the interval in this case. For the second, I use the change of variables $t=x-y$ (remember that $x$ is fixed for the integration).

Comment: Ok I get the second = now. I have not used the Lebesgue measure but maybe I can think of it as a usual integral? If so, then I think the 4th = sign is that "integrating from $x-2$ to $x-1$ for the integrand $t$ is the same as integrating over from $- \infty$ to $\infty$ for the integrand $1_{x-2, x-1} (t)$ correct? (Where $- \infty$ to $\infty$  rather is "for all values of $t$".  

And if that is true, then I do not get the fifth = sign because the primitive function of $t$ is $t^2$ but you apply some sort of logic here.

Comment: @jacob: Here I am using $m$ to denote the length of an interval. Yes regarding the 4th =. For the 5th, remember that you are integrating a function that only takes values $0,1$, not $t$.

Comment: Are we assuming anything in terms of the (in)dependence of X,Y?

Comment: Yep, see the first sentence above.