# calculate the probability of {X<Y}

Tags: probability

$X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,3]$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,4]$. What is the probability of the event $\{X<Y\}$?

Comment: the last part is {X<Y}

Comment: just edit it then...

Comment: See, e.g: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344844/distribution-of-a-difference-of-two-uniform-random-variables

Comment: X and Y can be only integers or any number?

Comment: It depends ... on how $X$ and $Y$ depend on the other

Comment: X AND Y are independent

Comment: Didn't we see this question last week?

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be solved using geometric probability.

Consider this picture [image: Geometric probability space]

Area covered with dots is the area of our interest where X < Y.
So the probability of {X < Y} equals to the proportion of this area to the full area of probability space: P(X < Y) = $\frac{9 / 2 + 3}{3 * 4} = 5/8$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using algebra way to solve the problem.

The density function contains contains two steps,

1. choosing arbitrary $x$
2. choosing $y$ that satisfy $x-y<0$

for the first step, the probability density function is $\frac{1}{3}$

for the second step, the probability density function is $\frac{4-x}{4}$

to combine two steps we need to form new density function by multiplying the two density functions. Then an integration through the whole x probability domain is needed, we get:

$\begin{align}P\{X-Y<0\}&=&\int_{0}^{3}{\frac{1}{3}*\frac{4-x}{4}dx}\\
&=&\frac{5}{8}\end{align}$