# How long will I wait for the bus?

Tags: probability

Buses from my home to the university arrive every t minutes. each bus can arrive within e minutes of it's scheduled time, When e is independent between buses and has a uniform distribution, so the arrival time for bus x is distributed uniformly between [xt-e,xt+e].

What is my expected time waiting for the bus at the station?

Comment: Check the related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344844/distribution-of-a-difference-of-two-uniform-random-variables

Comment: That question can tell me the difference between the arrival times, but my question assumes that I don't know the planned arrival time for the buses. (i.e. I know they come at xt but I don't know when is 0), So I arrive to the station at a practically random time